# Vue complains it can't find child component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to reuse an component app-address2 as a child of another one called app-delivery-creation2.

Error message:

> vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #app-address2

this is my main html file:

```
<div id="app-delivery-creation2">
    <delivery-creation2></delivery-creation2>
</div>

<script src="../assets/js/address.component2.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/delivery-creation.component2.js"></script>
```

and these are the components

```
Vue.component('form-address2', {
    template: '<div>child component</div>'
})
var appAddress = new Vue({
    el : '#app-address2'
})
```

and

```
Vue.component('delivery-creation2', {
    template :
        '<div class="container">' +
        '       <div id="app-address2">' +
        '           <form-address2></form-address2>' +
        '       </div>' +
        '</div>'
})
var appDeliveryCreation = new Vue({
    el : '#app-delivery-creation2'
})
```

QUESTION: why is vue saying it can't find element app-address2?

thank you very much

Comment: Why do you want `appAddress` as a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute:

```
var appAddress = new Vue({
    el : '#app-address2'
})
```

The element with id `app-address2` must **already** be in the DOM already.

But since you aren't declaring an element with such directly in your page (as you are with `<div id="app-delivery-creation2">`), it won't work. Notice you are declaring it as part of the template of another component:

```
Vue.component('delivery-creation2', {
    template :
        '<div class="container">' +
        '       <div id="app-address2">' +
        '           <form-address2></form-address2>' +
        '       </div>' +
        '</div>'
})
```

This means `<div id="app-address2">` will only be in the DOM **after** this code executes:

```
var appDeliveryCreation = new Vue({
    el : '#app-delivery-creation2'
})
```

Because the `<div id="app-delivery-creation2">` uses the `<delivery-creation2>`, that, when used, will "append" to the DOM the `<div id="app-address2">`.

In other words, for your code to work, you would have to have the `var appAddress = new Vue({` only run after the `var appDeliveryCreation = new Vue({` bit, like:

```
var appDeliveryCreation = new Vue({
    el : '#app-delivery-creation2'
})
var appAddress = new Vue({
    el : '#app-address2'
})
```

While it may work, this seems like some crazy inception-like idea. FWIW, you probably want to be doing something else.

Answer (score 0):

ok, my problem was that each file import was creating a new vue parent instance which was confusing vue...

more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50072075/1918003)

this fixed the issue

main HTML file - imports vue components

```
<div id="app-delivery-creation2">
    <delivery-creation2></delivery-creation2>
</div>

<script src="../assets/js/address.component2.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/delivery-creation.component2.js"></script>
```

address.component2.js

```
Vue.component('form-address2', {
    template: '<div>child component</div>'
})
```

delivery-creation.component2.js

```
Vue.component('delivery-creation2', {
    template :
        '<div class="container">' +
        '           <form-address2></form-address2>' +
        '</div>'
})
var appDeliveryCreation = new Vue({
    el : '#app-delivery-creation2'
})
```